# PointStyle doesn't reacts with the pointStyle used in datasets in doughnut chart in Chart JS

Tags: chart.js

I am using pointStyle in datasets of doughnut chart, but it seems like that's not reacting to the different types of point style except circle (which is default pointStyle for the datasets).

Below is the config I used,

```
 this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Netflix', 'Omnicell', 'Yahoo'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [10, 20, 30],
            label: 'No. of employees',
            backgroundColor: ['#c49616', '#218f26', '#e02f53'],
            pointStyle: 'rect',
            datalabels: {
              anchor: 'end',
            },
          }
        ],
      },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      options: <any>{
        layout: {
          padding: 20,
        },
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            backgroundColor: function (context: any) {
              return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
            },
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderRadius: 20,
            borderWidth: 3,
            color: 'white',
            display: function (context) {
              var dataset = context.dataset;
              var count = dataset.data.length;
              var value = dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
              return value > count * 1.5;
            },
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
            },
            padding: 6,
            formatter: Math.round,
            aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
            cutoutPercentage: 32,
            layout: {
              padding: 32,
            },
            elements: {
              line: {
                fill: true,
              },
              point: {
                hoverRadius: 7,
                radius: 5,
              },
            },
          },
          legend: {
            labels: {
              padding: 20,
              font: { size: 14 },
              usePointStyle: true,
            },
            position: 'right',
          },
          tooltip: { enabled: true },
        },
      },
    });
```

Slackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-doughnut-chart-c5rtn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This is a straightforward thing in case of line chart based on chart JS, but unlikely to happen with doughnut.

Comment: Got a clue, As in case of line chart this is straight forward, but for other types of charts we need to use `generateLabels()` callback function in order to manipulate the pointStyle shown in legends w.r.t to the pointStyle used in datasets.